# CopyMemory crashes Excel application

Tags: vba, excel, memory, multidimensional-array

A bit of background first.
I'm trying to merge multiple 2D arrays. Usualy I would loop through each element of new array and add them to existing array or place arrays' values on separate sheet and create new array from it but I'm working with large data.
Not long ago I found CopyMemory function and got realy excited by it, I've tested it on simple chunks of data first.
[image: Works fine]

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Sub Test()
    Dim varr0(), varr1(), Border As Long
    varr0 = Application.Transpose(Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value)
    Border = UBound(varr0, 2)
    varr1 = Application.Transpose(Range("a21").CurrentRegion.Value)
    ReDim Preserve varr0(1 To UBound(varr0, 1), 1 To UBound(varr0, 2) + UBound(varr1, 2))
    CopyMemory varr0(1, Border + 1), varr1(1, 1), UBound(varr1, 1) * UBound(varr1, 2) * 16
    Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(1, 10).Offset(UBound(varr0, 2) - 1, UBound(varr0, 1) - 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(varr0)
End Sub
```

Clearly it was a success (or so I thought) and I decided to work with pieces of my actual data, *from there it went downhill*.

```
Sub Test_2()
    Dim varr0(), varr1(), Border As Long, ws As Worksheet
    varr0 = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value)
    Border = UBound(varr0, 2)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            varr1 = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value)
            ReDim Preserve varr0(1 To UBound(varr0), 1 To UBound(varr0) + UBound(varr1))
            CopyMemory varr0(1, Border + 1), varr1(1, 1), UBound(varr1, 1) * UBound(varr1, 2) * 16
            Border = UBound(varr0, 2)
        End If
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ws1").Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(1, 11).Offset(UBound(varr0, 2) - 1, UBound(varr0, 1) - 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(varr0)
End Sub
```

Whenever I execute it, Excel crashes (it doesn't identify the error but warns that something went wrong (thanks cap)).
The only thing I can think of is that new data had strings in it.
Per [Source](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2) `Variant` requires only 16 bytes.

## My question(s) is:

- How do I make it work as intended?
- What flaw of my logic causes Excel to crash?
- Is it possible to merge two arrays without

  - Loops (or at least without iterating through whole array)
  - Use of sheets

### Update:

It seems I was calculating memory to copy incorrectly so I slightly modified my macro.

```
Sub Test_6()
    Dim varr0(), varr1(), Border As Long, ws As Worksheet, MemUsage As Long
    varr0 = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value)
    Border = UBound(varr0, 2)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            varr1 = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value)
            ReDim Preserve varr0(1 To UBound(varr0, 1), 1 To UBound(varr0, 2) + UBound(varr1, 2))
            MemUsage = VarPtr(varr1(UBound(varr1, 1), UBound(varr1, 2))) - VarPtr(varr1(1, 1))
            CopyMemory varr0(1, Border + 1), varr1(1, 1), MemUsage + 16 + Len(varr1(UBound(varr1, 1), UBound(varr1, 2)))
            Border = UBound(varr0, 2)
        End If
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(1, 11).Offset(UBound(varr0, 2) - 1, UBound(varr0, 1) - 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(varr0)
End Sub
```

In watch window I can clearly see that merge was successful, but shortly after `CopyMemory` line Excel crashes again.

Comment: Ill throw a couple of ideas for your last bullet: You can use the Join function (e.g., check [this](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/01/28/joining-two-dimensional-arrays/) post). To avoid multiple sheets, you may want to use global dynamic ranges, to which you can refer directly from your VBA code.

Comment: There's two issues with your approach. Due to the layout in the memory, 2D arrays can only be merged for an identical number of rows. You also need to clear the source with `RtlZeroMemory` to avoid the garbage collection of references (strings) when the source array is disposed of .

Comment: @FlorentB.this is why I transpose arrays (I have equal number of "columns"), can you clarify statement about `RtlZeroMemory`? I'm kinda new to this.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess that the API is reading a contiguous range of bytes in memory whereas the operating system may store large portions of data at split locations. Remember that VBA is using APIs to do its work. Once you override VBA and try to do the same job better the onus of proof is on you.

The following code will write the values of non-contiguous ranges of any source into a worksheet it creates. Note that the number of ranges is unlimited but is hard-coded.

```
Private Sub TestAppend()
    ' 17 Nov 2017

    Dim WsS As Worksheet, WsT As Worksheet          ' Source and Target
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim Rl As Long                                  ' last row
    Dim i As Long

    Set WsS = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WsT = Worksheets("Temp")
    If Err Then
        Set WsT = Worksheets.Add(Sheet1)
        WsT.Name = "Temp"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim Arr(1)
    Arr(0) = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Arr(1) = Range("E1").CurrentRegion.Value

    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        With WsT
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(Rl, "A").Resize(UBound(Arr(i)), UBound(Arr(i), 2)).Value = Arr(i)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that the rows limit for latest (and I don't use it) Excel is about 1 million rows, I think I won't be able to fit it on the sheet.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` returns 1,048,576. You might tweak the above code to continue writing in another column when this limit is breached. Frankly, I think you are shifting the goal posts. The solution I offered works for the problem you originally posed. The problem you now raise is how to have 2 million (?) rows in a worksheet.

Comment: I don't, realy: the goal was to merge arrays, not to collect data from different sources in one place. I did specify that solution without use of sheets/iteration through array is most favorable. Your answer is legit, since, in theory, I could store **Temp** values into array - I just can't implement it.

Comment: The prescribed way to append one array to another is to create a loop. You have forbidden loops and now disqualified a sheet-based solution which leaves you with only one option, make the `CopyMemory` work. Good luck with that! But let me ask you a question. Given an array of a million elements (already copied from its worksheet source), does it take an undue length of time to append it to another array via a loop? And would it take twice, five times, as much time if each element had 2 or 5 values? You would `Redim Preserve Arr1(UBound(Arr1) + UBound(Arr2))` once, not Redim on every loop.